# NullPointerException. Cannot create activity

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out where error is occurring. Here is the stack trace:

```
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834): Process: org.example.calcu, PID: 22834
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.calcu/org.example.calcu.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at org.example.calcu.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:79)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6084)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
08-16 18:00:36.455: E/AndroidRuntime(22834):    ... 12 more
```

This is where I try to start activity in my MainActivity:

`empty` is Button (fairly long and empty - no text in it). I swipe my finger left to create new intent - Menu

```
empty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.empty);
        empty.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){

             @Override
                public void onSwipeLeft() {
                Intent ent;
                ent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
                startActivity(ent);
             }
        });
```

This is activity that I try to create, Menu:

```
package org.example.calcu;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;




public class Menu extends MainActivity{

    Button blueTheme;
    View menu;

    class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

         private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

            public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
            }

            public void onSwipeRight() {
            }

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

                private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
                private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (distanceX > 0)
                            onSwipeRight();
                        else
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }   




    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("LOG", "menu opened!");
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        menu = (View) findViewById(R.layout.menu);
        menu.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){ /* this is line 79 */

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight(){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }


        });
        blueTheme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blueTheme);
        blueTheme.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            one.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#90CAF9"));    


            }
        });



}
}
```

Thanks for your help, and sorry I am pretty beginner in programming.

Comment: Just curious- why don't you use Navigation Drawer to show menu instead of showing in a whole other Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
menu = (View) findViewById(R.layout.menu);
```

`findViewById` takes an id as parameter not a layout.

The could should be:

```
menu = (View) findViewById(R.id.menu);
```

but, of course you also should have a `view` with id `menu` in your xml `layout`.

**To finish your activity and get back to the previous one:**

```
menu.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){
    @Override public void onSwipeRight()
    {
        Menu.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It make it work. One question, I again try to go back to previous view by swiping, it goes back but then all buttons does nothing, just an screen thats stopped working but didn't crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: how do you finish the activity?

Comment: Its a calculator app. Main activity have all interface, and in Menu I was thinking to create some options such as color changing. For now I have set it to change color of only one button. So calculator's activity will be finished upon exit.

Comment: you said that you can go back to the previous activity by swiping. what I meant what is the code you used to get back to the previous activity? you don't have it in the question.

Comment: It is in Menu,
` menu.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this){

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight(){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }`

Comment: I added that to my answer.